# Use columns (dataset fields) with whitespace in Report Builder

Tags: dataset, whitespace, reportbuilder

Can I have whitespace in a column name that I use in a dataset inside of Report Builder? E. g. from a query like

```
SELECT col as [red cards] FROM table
```

I get an error similar to (due to translation)

```
<Name>
Please enter a valid name. The name cannot contain any spaces...
```

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6a36b91c-84b0-4a61-9513-eacf48d40598/fields-with-white-spaces-not-shown-in-report?forum=sqlreportingservices) it is suggested to use underscores instead, but google shows precious little on the topic.

I am using the query somewhere else as well, so an as-descriptive-and-readable-as-possible name would be more desirable.

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work (I've just tested this it worked for me) with something this simple.  I have sometimes had issues with the use of alias in queries which have multiple joins.

If it still doesn't want to work, try RedCards or Red_Cards.